# bsxfun implementation in solving a min. optimization task

Tags: matlab, min, matrix-multiplication, bsxfun

I really need help with this one.

I have to matrices `L1` and `L2`, both are `(500x3)` of size.

First of all, I compute the difference of every element of each column of `L1` from `L2`  as follows:

```
lib1 = bsxfun(@minus, L1(:,1)',L2(:,1));
lib1=lib1(:);
lib2 = bsxfun(@minus, L1(:,2)',L2(:,2));
lib2=lib2(:);
lib3 = bsxfun(@minus, L1(:,3)',L2(:,3));
lib3=lib3(:);
LBR = [lib1 lib2 lib3];
```

The result is this matrix `LBR`. Then I have a `min`-problem to solve:

```
[d,p] = min((LBR(:,1) - var1).^2 + (LBR(:,2) - var2).^2 + (LBR(:,3) - var3).^2);
```

Which returns the point `p` where this `min`-problem is fulfied. Finally I can go back to my matrices `L1` and  `L2` to find the index-positions of the values which satisfy this `min`-problem. I done this as follows:

```
[minindex_alongL2, minindex_alongL1] = ind2sub(size(L1),p);
```

This is OK. But what I need now is:

I have to multiply , take the `tensor-product`, also called `Kronecker product` of a vector called `alpha` to `LBR`, `alpha` is given as follows:

```
alpha = 0:0.1:2;
```

And, this `Kronecker product` I have computed as follows:

```
val = bsxfun(@times,LBR,permute(alpha,[3 1 2]));
LBR = reshape(permute(val,[1 3 2]),size(val,1)*size(val,3),[]);
```

**what I need now is**: I need to solve the same `min`problem:

```
[d,p] = min((LBR(:,1) - var1).^2 + (LBR(:,2) - var2).^2 + (LBR(:,3) - var3).^2);
```

but, this time, in addition of finding the index-positions and values from `L1` and `L2` which satisfies this `min`-problem, I need to find the index position of the **single** value from the `alpha` vector which has been multiplied and which fulfills the `min`-problem. I don't have idea how can I do this so any help will be very appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Ps: I can post the `L1` and `L2` matrices if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need this correction in your code -

```
[minindex_alongL2, minindex_alongL1] = ind2sub([size(L2,1) size(L1,1)],p)
```

For the solution, you need to add the size of `p` into the index finding in the last step as the vector whose `min` is calculated has the "added influence" of `alpha` -

```
[minindex_alongL2, minindex_alongL1,minindex_alongalpha] = ind2sub([size(L2,1) size(L1,1) numel(alpha)],p)
```

`minindex_alongalpha` might be of your interest.

Comment: Hi @Divakar , I will try your suggestion tomorrow. Thank you very much for help...again :D

Comment: I am sorry that I had to try your suggestion, it was of course unnecessary to do it, your code works perfectly! :D I have actually tried many -variations- of `ind2sub` together with `alpha` but I didn't imagine that I was supposed to use `numel`, why is that? why `size(alpha)` didn't work? And, I am very sorry that I can just give you one upvote!  :)

Comment: @SergioHaram Since `alpha` is a row vector, `size(alpha,2)` would work instead of `numel(alpha)`. As I said earlier too, I am just too happy to answer any queries on `bsxfun` :) So keep 'em comming!!