# Finding index-positions after -spatial- matrix multiplication. bsxfun implemented

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication, bsxfun

I need help finding some index-positions of a matrix and two vectors after a complicated matrix multiplication, please bear with me and read what I have first, my question comes at the end.

I have two matrices `L1` and `L2`:

```
L1 = firstMatrix;
L2 = secondMatrix;
```

I need to compute the difference (column-wise) of every single value from `L1` with all the values of `L2`, again, in column-wise form, this is done as follows:

**step one**

```
lib1 = bsxfun(@minus, L1(:,1)',L2(:,1));
lib1=lib1(:);
lib2 = bsxfun(@minus, L1(:,2)',L2(:,2));
lib2=lib2(:);
lib3 = bsxfun(@minus, L1(:,3)',L2(:,3));
lib3=lib3(:);
```

At the end I have my new matrix `LBR`:

```
LBR = [lib1 lib2 lib3];
```

Now, I have two vectors `alpha` and `beta` -given on a closed domain with same step-size, in this case they are the same-.

```
alpha = 0:0.1:2;
beta = 0:0.1:2;
```

I need now to compute the tensor-product, I can do it in two ways:

**step two**

**first way**:

```
alphat1 = kron(alpha,lib1);
alphat2 = kron(alpha,lib2);
alphat3 = kron(alpha,lib3);
T1 = [alphat1 alphat2 alphat3];
betat1 = kron(beta,lib1);
betat2 = kron(beta,lib2);
betat3 = kron(beta,lib3);
T2 = [betat1 betat2 betat3];
```

Or, **the second way**, which is by means of the `bsxfun` from matlab:

```
val = bsxfun(@times,LBR,permute(alpha,[3 1 2]));
T = reshape(permute(val,[1 3 2]),size(val,1)*size(val,3),[]);

val2 = bsxfun(@times,LBR,permute(beta,[3 1 2]));
T2 = reshape(permute(val2,[1 3 2]),size(val2,1)*size(val2,3),[]);
```

My problem:

I need to find the `min-distance` in the following way, first, I have of course three constants:

```
gama1 = value1;
gama2 = value2;
gama3 = value3;
```

And the `min-distance` is computed as follows:

**step three**

```
[d,p] = min(((T(:,1)-T2(:,1))-gama1).^2 + ((T(:,2)-T2(:,2))-gama2).^2 +
((T(:,3)-T2(:,3))-gama3).^2);
d = sqrt(d);
```

I need, very much, the index positions of `L1`, `L2`, `alpha` and `beta` which are fulfilling this `min-distance` problem.

I have tried the following:

**step four**

```
[minindex_alongL2, minindex_alongL1, minindex_alongalpha, minindex_alongbeta] = 
ind2sub([size(L2,1) size(L1,1) numel(alpha) numel(beta)],p);
```

But it doesn't work. I would appreciate very much all the help you can provide me!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Divakar, I am doing what you asked me for :D giving you more `bsxfun` questions! I really tried to find a solution, believe me I do, but when I am posting my questions here is because I really need help. So if you have any suggestions! The only difference this case with the case before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24181012/bsxfun-implementation-in-solving-a-min-optimization-task is that I have two vectors which I am tensor-multiplying.

Comment: +1 For the well formulated question. Understandability is well above average.

Comment: Thank you very much @Trilarion :) I know that a good question is very appreciated at the `OP` and it will help me to get a good answer too! So, yes! it is worthy to spend time writing good questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alpha` and `beta` gets `T` and `T2` respectively. Then you are performing columnwise subtraction between `T` and `T2` and not a subtraction for each element of a column in `T` against all elements of the same column number in `T2`. If you would like to perform the latter, you are most probably needed to change the codes from ground up and getting rid of concatenations and extending into multi-dimensional arrays.

Continuing with what you have in your codes, you can at most get joint `alpha-beta` indices and not separate indices for `alpha` and `beta`.

Thus, you can have something like -

```
[minindex_alongL2, minindex_alongL1, minindex_alongalphabeta] = ind2sub([size(L2,1) size(L1,1) numel(alpha)],p)
```

**Edit 1:** Assuming you are inputting values for `L1`, `L2`, `value1`, `value2`, `value3` and row vectors `alpha` and `beta`, see if this code works for you -

```
lib1 = bsxfun(@minus, L1(:,1)',L2(:,1)); %%//'
lib2 = bsxfun(@minus, L1(:,2)',L2(:,2)); %%//'
lib3 = bsxfun(@minus, L1(:,3)',L2(:,3)); %%//'

t1 = cat(3,lib1,lib2,lib3);
t2 = permute(alpha,[4 3 1 2]);
T = bsxfun(@times,t1,t2);

t22 = permute(beta,[4 3 1 2]);
T2 = bsxfun(@times,t1,t22);

gama1 = value1;
gama2 = value2;
gama3 = value3;

mat1 = bsxfun(@minus,T,permute(T2,[1 2 3 5 4]));
mat2 = bsxfun(@minus,mat1,permute([gama1;gama2;gama3],[3 2 1]));
mat2 = squeeze(sum(mat2,3));

[d,p] = min(mat2(:));
d = sqrt(d);

[minindex_alongL2, minindex_alongL1, minindex_alongalpha, minindex_alongbeta] = ind2sub([size(L2,1) size(L1,1) numel(alpha) numel(beta)],p)
```

Comment: Hi @Divakar I don't want to loose practice so here I am, coming with a question to you, again :) In the part of your code: `mat1 = bsxfun(@minus,T,permute(T2,[1 2 3 4]));` I am having problems running a _little_ big `L1, L2 alpha and beta` vectors. I get from `matlab`: `Error using bsxfun. Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options. Error in (line 97)
mat1 = bsxfun(@minus,T,permute(T2,[1 2 3 5 4]));` Any idea how could I fix this issue? In advance thanks.

Comment: `L1 and L2` are `(1000x3)` each and `alpha beta` are `(1x50)` each. May be there is a way to transpose `alpha and beta`, will this help?

Comment: @SergioHaram `bsxfun` is known to be memory hungry and you are running into the same. Not sure if there's a way around it when sticking to `bsxfun`.

Comment: I see, well, I will try to reduce the size of the inputs parameters and see how it goes. :)

Comment: I believe I may be force to see another options here, since this `kron` product I am computing: `L1` and `alpha` for example, give just a vector of dim `50 000 x 3` which is not so big... :( May be I can split the vectors in, let's say three? may be this will just complicate things even more...

Comment: @SergioHaram Exactly, splitting could be done, but then too many complications there with splitting + rejoining. How  about `kron`? Is it working with such large datasets?

Comment: my friend I have reformulated the problem... I have a new question which, I hope, shows the min distance problem in a more general way so it can be "attacked" from different angles. The question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24363552/iteration-of-matrix-vector-multiplication-which-stores-specific-index-positions PS `kron` works fine

Comment: Hi!, I am bothering you again. I just have a little question. In the step three of my question you can see that I am squaring every element in the sum, is this done in your answer-code? because I cannot find it, may be it should be `mat2 = squeeze(sum(mat2,3).^2)`; ? or Am I wrong? thanks! :) PS. the reason I have noticed this is because I am getting d which is the distance, with imaginary numbers(!)

Comment: @SergioHaram Hey again!:) Well it must be `mat2 = squeeze(sum(mat2.^2,3));`. Sorry about the bug there :) I promise, I would clean up the code soon!